# Find related directive to element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm just curious but I was wondering if there was a way to target an element and grab it's controlling directive. ie. something like angular.element('#id').directive().

If there's no direct way of doing this, I have a backup but I think it would be rather neat.

Thanks.

Comment: What would you do with it once you "grab" it?

Comment: @Stewie A bunch of things, this isn't really a matter of using a different "correct" implementation. I'm just experimenting at this point and will worry about the Angular way later. I'm just looking for a way to access the directive controlling a particular element (specifically the controller $scope so I can trigger methods and change variables on it). I've already written a service that lets directives communicate with each other, but I want to see if it's possible to access the directive via the element. Thoughts on the most performant method are appreciated.

Comment: Directives can expose their API through the use of directive controllers. Directive `A` defines it's controller and exposes methods on it, and directive `B` gets hold of that controller by "requiring" directive `A`: Directive B's DDO: `{..., require: "A", scope:{}, link: fn(scope,elm,attrs,Actrl){}, ...)`. But maybe it's best if you could provide some code, showing your intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have posed the question incorrectly and confused people. All I was looking for was the .scope() method which you can call off an angular.element() selection. Seems to work nicely.